# React not re-rendering after Redux state Update

Tags: reactjs, redux

My inputValue value is being reset to 0 after addAmount is called. I can see the store is being updated to 0 via redux tools, however my input value is not resetting to 0. I know mutating react/redux state is a common issue, but I just can't work it out.

I have cut out code due to post restrictions.

**Reducer**

```
case actions.RESET_INPUT_VALUE:
          return {
            ...state,
            inputValue: action.payload
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }};
```

**Actions**

```
export const resetInputValue = value => ({
  type: actions.RESET_INPUT_VALUE,
  payload: value
});
```

**React Component**

```
class TheBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  addAmount = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const addToTotal =
      this.props.state.dayIntakeAmount + this.props.state.inputValue;
    this.props.onAddAmount(addToTotal, this.props.state.date);
    this.props.onResetInputValue(0);
    console.log(this.props.state.inputValue);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.props.onInputChange(e.target.value);
  };


              <form onSubmit={this.addAmount}>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  required
                  name="inputValue"
                  value={this.props.state.inputValue}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  suffix="ml"
                />

                <Button
                  success
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={this.props.state.inputValue <= 0}
                >
                  ADD
                </Button>
              </form>


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onAddAmount: (amount, date) => dispatch(plusIntakeAmount(amount, date)),
  onInputChange: value => dispatch(onInputChange(value)),
  onResetInputValue: value => dispatch(resetInputValue(value))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TheBox);
```

Comment: Try implementing the method ``componentDidUpdate`` to listen for changes on the props. Stateful react components do not rerender on props change automatically, but only call the method ``componentDidUpdate``.

Comment: I added `componentDidUpdate(){console.log('updated)}` and it logged correctly., but the value is still in the input box.

Comment: Everything was correct. I forgot to add a `value={props.value}` to my Input component, so it wasn't reading the value. Thanks for your help.